# Is it possible to replace static methods with a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, localization

The problem I want to solve is that i have to rebuild my application in case a language file gets updated.

I have an existing class, which is autogenrated from a ResX file. The auto generated part looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
///   Looks up a localized string similar to OK.
/// </summary>
public static string MenuOk {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("MenuOk", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

In my code I have many calls like this:

```
var text = Strings.MenuOk;
```

which gets the key from the ResourceManager. I'm thinking of switching to a Dictionary to get my Strings instead of the `ResourceManager`. This Dictionary is filled at program start.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're going to have to access a dictionary like this

```
var text = myDictionary["MenuOk"];
```

anyway, why not just wrap `ResourceManager` so you don't have to supply `resourceCulture` every time?

```
public static string GetString(string key)
{
    return ResourceManager.GetString(key, ResourceCulture);
}

// ...

var text = MyResourceManager.GetString("MenuOk");
```

Comment: wrapping the ResourceManager is an excelent idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always create your own XML based language files and use those in your code.

This way you keep the binaries compiled and just change the extra language file, but this way you have to keep track of several files not just the binaries.

Comment: That was exactly my idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MEF to dynamically load dlls and classes at runtime. If you never used it, it might be a bit over the top though.

You can use some reflection otherwise, but I doubt that's the direction you want.

I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Mabye you can have them implement an Interface, and simply swap the instance of the implementation otherwise.